# C# How to output multiple sql data to text? (Single query is working)

Tags: c#, sql, textbox, sqldatareader

I'm searching for a tip or a code sample to output multiple records within my SQL database with the same name, called Auftragsnummer but differently second values called Stellplatz, to a textbox.

This is my working code, to output one search query to two textboxes:

```
private void search_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM[FAUF] WHERE Auftragsnummer = '" + txt_search.Text + "'", con);
        mdr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (mdr.Read())
        {
            txt_searchNr.Text = mdr["Auftragsnummer"].ToString();
            txt_searchSF.Text = mdr["Stellplatz"].ToString();
            txt_search.SelectAll();
        }
        else
        {
            txt_searchNr.Text = "---";
            txt_searchSF.Text = "---";
            txt_search.SelectAll();
            MessageBox.Show("Keine Daten gefunden - Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Eingaben!");

        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

The user can add the Auftragsnummer multiple times with differently second values named Stellplatz.

```
Example:
102555 - > 3
102555 - > 7
```

How I get the second record from my SQL database into a second output within my Code?

Comment: As explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader): `while (reader.Read()) { /* a new row is available */ }`

Comment: [Please don't add an extra question into your original post, instead if you have a new question, ask a new one and link it to this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267964/is-this-rollback-worthy)

Answer (score 1):

Close Con and open it again and write new query

Answer (score 1):

You while loop until mdr.Read() is unavailable to resolve your problem:

```
     private void search_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM[FAUF] WHERE Auftragsnummer = '" + txt_search.Text + "'", con);
            mdr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (!mdr.Read())
            {
                txt_searchNr.Text = "---";
                txt_searchSF.Text = "---";
                txt_search.SelectAll();
                MessageBox.Show("Keine Daten gefunden - Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Eingaben!");
                con.Close();
                return;
            }

            while (mdr.Read())
            {
                //Do your code here
            }

            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your sample :) My problem is now, that the latest record is shown in my output, but the second record is not shown in the second texboxes. I want to fill in with the first record TextAuftrag1 and TextST1 and with the second record another pair named like TextAuftrag2 and TextST2.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is now working for two records but when there is only one record in the database, the output seems to be empty.

```
        if (!mdr.Read())
        {
            txt_searchNr.Text = "---";
            txt_searchSF.Text = "---";
            txt_searchNr1.Text = "---";
            txt_searchSF1.Text = "---";
            MessageBox.Show("Keine Daten gefunden - Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Eingaben!");
            con.Close();
            return;
        }

        if (mdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (mdr.Read())
            {
                txt_searchNr.Text = mdr["Auftragsnummer"].ToString();
                txt_searchSF.Text = mdr["Stellplatz"].ToString();

                while (mdr.Read())
                    {
                        txt_searchNr1.Text = mdr["Auftragsnummer"].ToString();
                        txt_searchSF1.Text = mdr["Stellplatz"].ToString();
                    }
                mdr.NextResult();
            }

        }
        con.Close();
```